# RecyclerView don't have Item click and other events

Tags: c#, android, events, xamarin

Earlier I used `ListView` and there was lots of events in this class, but now I started to use `RecyclerView` and here I can't find any event.

for example:

```
RecyclerView mView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);
mView.ItemClick += delegate {
// action
};
```

is not working with this class - RecyclerView.

Actually these events whitch I want exist in RecyclerView.Adapter so I tried this:

```
public class ListItemArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int itemPosition;

    public ListItemArgs(int pos)
    {
        itemPosition = pos;
    }
}

public class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    public event EventHandler<ListItemArgs> OnItemLongClick;

    // some overrides skipped (not needed anyway)

    public class MyView : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public View mMainView { get; set; }
        public TextView mName { get; set; } 
        public TextView mEventCount { get; set; } 
        public CheckBox mFavorite { get; set; }

        public MyView(View view) : base(view)
        {
            mMainView = view;
        }
    }

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        MyView mHolder = holder as MyView;

        mHolder.mMainView.LongClick += delegate
        {
            Snackbar.Make(mRecyclerView, "Ar tikrai norite trinti pasirinkimą?", Snackbar.LengthLong).Show();
            OnItemLongClick.Invoke(mHolder.mMainView, new ListItemArgs(position));
        };
    }
}
```

and declarations in other class:

```
RecyclerView mView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);
RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter new AddNewDayAdapter(mView);
```

> And now I should be able to launch this event from `mAdapter` object, which leter I use to `SetAdapter` for my `RecyclerView`. (code below)

```
mAdapter.OnItemLongClick += (object sender, ListItemArgs e) =>
{
    // action
}
mView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);
```

> but `mAdapter.OnItemLongClick` is not working.

Main question: how can I get an event in which args would be view of row and selected item position ?

Comment: What is mMainView and where is your corresponding FindViewById call for it?

Comment: mMainView is RowLayout